# Pandas dataframe currency to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there is other similar topics, but I have tried all of them and did not succeed.
I am reading in a dataframa of which one column('Gross') is full of currencies (like $2,553.00)

This is how I read in the dataframe:

```
columns=['Client','year','month','traffic','Source','Leads','Sold','Gross']             
return pd.read_csv(filename,thousands=',',decimal=".", index_col='Client',parse_dates=True,encoding = "ISO-8859-1",usecols=columns)
```

I have now tried several ways to convert the currency column to floats in order to do calculations with them, for example the following:

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
data['Gross'] = data['Gross'].fillna(0.0).str.replace(r'[$,-]', '').astype('float')
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\tool5.py", line 136, in <module>
    data=getData()
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\tool5.py", line 123, in getData
    data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4877, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4973, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\tool5.py", line 123, in <lambda>
    data = data.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3610, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 54, in __get__
    return self.construct_accessor(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 1910, in _make_accessor
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string "
AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index year')
[Finished in 7.4s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\crmtool5.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Laila\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Or:

```
data[['Gross']] = data[['Gross']].replace('[\$]','',regex=True).replace("-", "",regex=True).replace(',','.', regex=True)
data[['Gross']] = data[['Gross']].fillna(0.0).astype('float')
```

giving me a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\crmtool5.py", line 136, in <module>
    data=getData()
  File "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\crmtool5.py", line 121, in getData
    data[['Gross']] = data[['Gross']].fillna(0.0).astype('float')
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4004, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3462, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3329, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 544, in astype
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 625, in _astype
    values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 703, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
[Finished in 7.9s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Laila\Desktop\crmtool5.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Laila\Desktop]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

An example of the raw data:

```
Client  year    month   traffic Source  Leads   Sold    Gross
dd      2018    March   6,778    x      0       1       -$27
dd      2018    March   6,778    yy     1       0       $0
dd      2018    March   6,778    z      2       1       $1,354
```

Any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: It's hard to know what is causing the `ValueError: could not convert string to float` in `.astype('float')` (2nd example) without seeing your data.  Can you isolate and share a small chunk of data that you are running this code on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to replace `,` with `.` but the resulting string can not be converted to float. For example, 2.553.00 contains two dots and when converting it to float an exception will be thrown.

Change the code to:

```
data['Gross'] = data['Gross'].fillna(0.0).str.replace('[$,]', '').astype('float')
```

Comment: I then have  a problem with negative currencies (ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-')

Comment: @LailaVanMents: It sounds like one of the rows contains only a single '-', with no numbers. You could replace that with a 0 by doing a `replace('-$', '0.0')` before `astype('float')`.